# Using get_name() with attachment files in a list

Tags: list, url, html, attachments, file

I am trying to retrieve the names of two attached files that a single item may contain in a list

I'm not sure how this function works, but here is what I have so far

```
var PicName1 = '';
var PicName2 = '';
  for (var file in attachmentFiles) {
    if (attachmentFiles.itemAt(i)) {
      PicName1 = attachmentFiles.itemAt[i].get_name(0);
      PicName2 = attachmentFiles.itemAt[i].get_name(1);
    } 
    i++
  }
```

I went out on a limb with `get_name(0)` and `get_name(1)` in hoping that it would find the name of the first and second file in that item. However, both of them return the name of the final attachment in the item (this is the same result as `get_name()`).

The `get_name()` function returns the following stared value in a URL that points to a list item

```
site.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/Lists/ContactList/Attachments/1/**PhotoName1.jpg**
```

Is there a way I can extract the name of each file like this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var pictureName = PicName1.substring(PicName1.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

In your case it will return "PhotoName1.jpg"

[Look this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302306/how-to-pull-the-file-name-from-a-url-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! Will this method also work for extracting PhotoName2.jpg? Of the same item. ie: site.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/Lists/ContactList/Attachments/1/**PhotoName2.jpg**

Comment: Yeah..just change variable PicName1 to PicName2 in above code.